# How to pack iphone code

Tags: iphone

i created an iphone app and tested it on my simulator its working fine , now i want to test the same app in another simulator . How can i do the same (i copied the whole folder but its not working ) please help

Comment: Why not deploy the project on the other computer... then you have it in the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just copy all the project code to another machine, using Xcode to rebuild the project on the simulator there.

If you meant " (i copied the whole folder but its not working ) " is copying the whole project code already then it is really strange.

Another recommended way is using a Version Control System like [svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/) or [git](http://github.com/), which will do many jobs for you like pushing, pulling, keeping track of histories

Answer (score 1):

If they are running the same version of the Simulator, and you don't mind deleting and overwriting any apps or data on the target users's Simulator, you can just copy over your entire "~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/" directory contents.